# AFL++ not taking entire input as a seed

Tags: c, fuzzing

I am trying to fuzz zint and the problem is that my initial input is taken as half, for example CODE128 is taken as CODE only, I need to first let it hit all the branches using the correct input. Can anyone help me with this? This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h> // Include this header for uint8_t
#include "zint.h"

// The target function to be fuzzed
extern "C" int LLVMFuzzerTestOneInput(const uint8_t *data, size_t size) {

// Initialize Zint
struct zint_symbol* symbol = ZBarcode_Create();

// Set the input data as the message to be encoded
ZBarcode_Encode_and_Buffer(symbol, data, size, 0);

// Free resources
ZBarcode_Delete(symbol);

return 0;
}
```

I tried using different methods of input but I still got a half original input seed. `